# Kit created on fontawesome.com complaining about "Not allowed when Origin missing"

Tags: font-awesome

I created a kit on font-awesome and then grabbed the API token and installed the wordpress plugin from fontawesome and set the plugin to use my kit.

Every time I reload the page I see the following error in the developer console:

```
staging.asbestos.co.za/:78     GET https://kit.fontawesome.com/bb44dac6ab.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
```

When accessing the url directly I see the following error response:

```
Not allowed when Origin missing
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to add the fontawesome kit that I created through their dashboard to my wordpress site using the fontawesome plugin for wordpress that is also developed by the fontawesome team.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the reason I was getting the "Not allowed when Origin missing" is because if you access the https://kit.fontawesome.com/bb44dac6ab.js directly, it is not coming from an origin. So it would naturally fail.

I managed to solve the issue myself by checking the site url of my websites domain that I had added to the list of allowed domains in the kits settings. I had accidentally made a typo in the domain name that I added. I corrected the typo and now it's all working :-) Thank you